# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') at MatKeyboardKeyComponent._setCursorPosition in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

In my project, I'm using ngx7-material-keyboard for the virtual keyboard all this code was written long back they didn't use formGroup, when I enter any kay in the virtual keyboard I'm getting this error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')  at MatKeyboardKeyComponent._setCursorPosition and also not able get the events.

Please help me to fix this issue,
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

code:-
TS:-

```
import {MatKeyboardRef, MatKeyboardComponent, MatKeyboardService } from 'ngx7-material-keyboard';

openKeyboard(type: string) {
    if (this.keyboardService.isOpened && this.keyboardType === type) {
      this.keyboardService.dismiss();
      this.keyboardRef = undefined;
    } else {
      this.keyboardType = type;
      if (type === 'primary') {
        this.keyboardRef = this.keyboardService.open(this.primaryKeyboard);
      } else if (type === 'secondary') {
        this.keyboardRef = this.keyboardService.open(this.secondaryKeyboard);
      }
      if (this.selectedField) {
        this.selectedField.focus();
      }
    }
  }

scrollPage(
    element: HTMLElement,
    type: string,
    formControlName: string,
    index: number
  ) {
    this.selectedField = element;
    if (this.keyboardRef) {
      this.keyboardRef.instance.setInputInstance(
        this.attachToElementMesOne._results[index]
      );
    }
  }
```

HTML:-

```
 <input #keyboardRef #{{field.name}} id="{{field.name}}"
 (blur)="captureValue($event, field.name, 'primary')"
 (focus)="scrollPage(field.name, 'primary', field.name, I)" matInput
 placeholder="{{field.label[primaryLang] | translate}}"
 [value]="primaryData[field.name]" required={{field.ismandatory}}
 *ngIf="field.name !== 'fieldVal'" readonly=true />
```

I tried with keyup event to take user entered data but it is not working, I want to capture the user entered data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.